# Bertrand series: Why is $\frac{1}{n^{\alpha}log^{\beta}(n)}$ not bounded for $\alpha < 0$

Tags: sequences-and-series

Why is $$\frac{1}{n^{\alpha}log^{\beta}(n)}$$ not bounded for $\alpha < 0$?

---

This concerns: 
 http://www.sosmath.com/calculus/series/bertrand/bertrand.html

Comment: Becasue $n^{-\alpha}$ grows much faster to infinity for $\alpha<0$ than the logarithm does, (if it does at all, that is, if $\beta>0$; if $\beta \leq 0$ then you just have positive powers of sequences tending to infinity)

Comment: @uniquesolution Why does it grow faster?

Comment: Here, read this. http://www.math.uconn.edu/~kconrad/blurbs/analysis/growth.pdf

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2563446/on-convergence-of-bertrand-series-sum-limits-n-2-infty-frac1n-alpha